# pod install - Podfile.lock updated

Tags: cocoapods

I've just cloned a project with several pods locked.

After a `pod install` my Podfile.lock gets modified.

Why ?

Isn't it supposed to be updated only if I do `pod update` ?

---

**Podfile**

```rb
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'SVProgressHUD',    '~> 0.9'
pod 'Reachability',     '~> 3.1.0'
pod 'UIDeviceAddition', '~> 1.0'
pod 'CorePlot',         '~> 1.3'
pod 'RestKit',          '~> 0.20'
pod 'ZipArchive',       '~> 1.1.0'
```

*^- not changed -^*

**Diff**

```diff
index c82dc53..e408a71 100644
--- a/Podfile.lock
+++ b/Podfile.lock
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 PODS:
-  - AFNetworking (1.3.2)
+  - AFNetworking (1.3.4)
   - CorePlot (1.3)
   - Reachability (3.1.1)
   - RestKit (0.20.3):
@@ -32,14 +32,14 @@ DEPENDENCIES:
   - ZipArchive (~> 1.1.0)

 SPEC CHECKSUMS:
-  AFNetworking: 7f9bcd7c287a75476cd5c61e82fd3380e93e4c54
-  CorePlot: af8307dd1fc013b3d8d97f54db8de0de6d57af84
-  Reachability: 2be6bc2fd2bd31d97f5db33e75e4b29c79e95883
# ...
+  AFNetworking: 80c4e0652b08eb34e25b9c0ff3c82556fe5967b4
+  CorePlot: f62846d49870dcb5a7fffa42f493faf836155578
+  Reachability: 8e9635e3cb4f98e7f825e51147f677ecc694d0e7
# ...

-COCOAPODS: 0.22.3
+COCOAPODS: 0.33.1
```

Comment: Can you post the diff?

Comment: can you post your pod file? did you make any changes to it?

Answer (score 1):

This may happen due to various reasons. For example, pod master repo got updated and somebody installed pods after running `pod repo update`, while on your machine you still have an old version of the repository.

Alternatively, it could also happen if you change the `CocoaPods` tool version. The checksums changed, this is absolutely normal. Commit the newly created checksums to the repository and continue using newer version of the tool.

Answer (score -2):

Pod install and pod update share the same machinery.

Pod install will lock the version of the dependencies not changed in the Podfile.
Pod update instead tries to update any pod

so only if you made changes to the Podfile the podfile.lock can change

Comment: Yes that's the behavior I was expecting, but I haven't changed anything in my `Podfile`. Also why Cocoapods version gets locked ? What happen if multiple developers install the pods with different Cocoapods version ? Isn't going to increase the chance conflict on this file anyway ?

Comment: i see you didn't lock the version of AFNetworking so thats what mush have been triggering the update

Comment: `AFNetworking` is a dependency of `RestKit` and both was previously locked into the lock file. `pod install` should only install the revisions locked here, shouldn't it ?